# jquery datePicker not working inside bootsrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, popover

I have popover in which I placed html contents. In side popover I have text box which shows calendar. This works if textbox is outside popover but same function not working inside popover.

```
<div id="status2_popover" class="status-popover" style="display: none">
     <div>
         <span class="field-heading">Confirm Date</span>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="date-time-picker field-pitch in-popover-text-box"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE

```
<div id="status1UpdateBox" class="update-box" data-placement='bottom' data-toggle="popover">
                               <strong>Booked</strong> <asp:Label ID="Lblstatus1Date" runat="server" Text="10/10/2016"></asp:Label> <asp:Label ID="LblStatus1Time" runat="server" Text="10.30am"></asp:Label>
                           </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#status1UpdateBox').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
            return $('#status1_popover').html();
        }
     });
   });
</script>
```

datepicker jquery

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');
        $('.date-time-picker').datetimepicker({
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
        });
```

Comment: What does this "not working" means? Is it not showing? or css issues?

Comment: @Nitheesh No it's not showing. May be inside popover it's not calling datepicker class.

Comment: Any error logs in console when the initialization function is called?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the bootstrap popover library?

The problem is probably that when you setup the datetimepicker the content of the popover does not exist. You have to initialise the datetimepicker when the popover has been created. Assuming you are using the bootstap popover you could do it like this...

```
 $('#status1UpdateBox').on("shown.bs.popover", function() {
     var popover = $(e.target).data('bs.popover');
     popover.$tip.find(".date-time-picker").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
    });
 })
```

Comment: With your code script gets called but datepicker class not working

Comment: In your initial question can you provide the code (html) that is used to trigger the popover ("#status1UpdateBox)

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry had to do some actual work, which datetimepicker library are you using? This one.. http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ ?

Comment: Yes. I am using that only.

Comment: Ok I've made a little change the problem with my previous answer was that when a popover displays the content it changes the id of the div, I have modified the code to get the right content div to then initialise the datepicker